# Can't push from useEffect a new item in array

Tags: reactjs

I have the next situation in my react application:

```js
export default function App() {
  const arr  = []
  useEffect(() => {
    arr.push('test')
  },[])
  console.log(arr)
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {
          arr.map((i) => <span>{i}</span>)
        }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Above i try to push a new item in the array. So in the `console.log(arr)` i expect to have `['test']`. Why it does not happen? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mayer-pxswq?file=/src/App.js:59-294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` runs in the next frame, so it won't be populated until later.

You should try this:

```
  const arr  = []
  useEffect(() => {
    arr.push('test')
    console.log(arr)
  },[])
```

You also don't want to be setting state like that, use `useState`.

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  setArr(a => [...a, 'test'])
}, [arr])
```

Comment: how i can get the `arr` values outside useEffect?

Comment: through useState.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the state hook for your `arr`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setArr([...arr, "test"]);
  }, []);
  console.log(arr);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((i) => (
        <span>{i}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is working but the console.log is not at the good place.
Your console.log is login before the useEffect();

```js
export default function App() {
  const arr  = []
  useEffect(() => {
    arr.push('test');
    console.log('After UseEffect', arr);
  },[])
  console.log('Before UseEffect',arr)
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {
          arr.map((i) => <span>{i}</span>)
        }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider `three point` below:

1. You should use `useState` hook.

So Use

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
```

Not

```
const arr  = []
```

> When you use `React` you must consider `useState` because when you update any variable using `useState` Hook then `React` will update the `state` and can be able to `rerender` your component. Otherwise, your component will not be updated.

2. You should not push directly into the array `arr`.

So Use

```
setArr(item => [...item, newItem])
```

Not

```
arr.push('test')
```

> As I explain it above, if you dont use `setArr` then `React` will not update your component.

3. You should use key when you use multiple html element using map function.

So Use

```
{arr.map((a, i) => (
            <span key={i}>{a}</span>
          ))}
```

Not

```
arr.map((i) => <span>{i}</span>)
```

> [Keys help React identify](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

**Here is the complete example:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let newItem = 'test';
    setArr(item => [...item, newItem]); // Here we are using `spread operator` to use previous items from `arr`
    console.log(arr);
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((a, i) => (
        <span key={i}>{a}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, useEffect run after console.log so arr still empty when log,

Agree with @Stoobish, but:

1. Tracking arr change should use useDebugValue or log inside useEffect
2. If you want to prevent duplicate render when state change, use useEffectLayout instead of useEffect.

```
    import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setArr([...arr, "test"]);
      }, []);
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(arr);
      }, [arr])
      return (
        <div className="App">
          {arr.map((i) => (
            <span key={i}>{i}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
```